# Multi-boot -- How to safely delete a distro?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, kubuntu

I have multi-boot, and everything is on the same hard disk.
After my Windows partitions come my Manjaro partitions (efi, swap, root). And after that is my single Kubuntu 19.10 partition (it has no swap partition, and no dedicated efi partition).

Problem is this: if I delete my Manjaro partitions, it causes Kubuntu to boot super slow. How to prevent this issue from happening, or alternatively, how to heal it?

EDIT: Maybe Kubuntu is using the Manjaro swap, and if so, how to stop that behavior?

```
cat /etc/fstab
# <file system> <mount point> <type> <options> <dump> <pass>

UUID=9242ef31-5b4c-4868-9060-a20e36536a79       /       ext4    errors=remount-ro      01
UUID=FD3A-C390  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
UUID=fdf6d201-faf5-4609-8d71-462dce3041a9       none    swap    sw      0       0
/dev/disk/by-uuid/01D5B97BB5271110      /mnt/01D5B97BB5271110   auto    nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0       0
/dev/disk/by-uuid/22EC446AEC4439F5      /mnt/22EC446AEC4439F5   auto    nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0       0
/dev/disk/by-uuid/65924102-c27b-4bd3-a0b6-e8667989fb8d  /mnt/65924102-c27b-4bd3-a0b6-e8667989fb8d       auto    nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0       0
```

[image]

Comment: If you boot, but slow, then you must have in your fstab, the mount of the now missing partition(s). Check your fstab. It has to time out if it cannot find a missing partition. Compare `cat /etc/fstab` UUIDs to existing UUIDs with `lsblk -f`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the helpful comment from @oldfred, I checked more carefully, and found that Kubuntu was looking for the Manjaro swap partition. Apparently, that old swap partition was detected during the Kubuntu installation, and it was employed, instead of creating a swap file, which is usually done by default with new Ubuntu installations.

So the answer to my question is:

1 Disable Kubuntu's use of the swap partition

2 Create and enable a swap file

I was successful in both steps, following this tutorial:
https://www.linuxuprising.com/2018/08/how-to-use-swap-file-instead-of-swap.html

Afterwards, I deleted all the Manjaro partitions, and Kubuntu still boots up at least as fast as before.